# Roll back a change with Team Foundation Server Source Control

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

I'm having a real hard time rolling back a change under TFS Source Control. I've followed the [instructions in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194956%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) with no success.

The instructions basically go like this:

1. Get the old version for source control (files get copied to local workspace)
2. Check out the local version
3. Check in

The problem is that when checking out, the latest version is automatically fetched from source control, overwriting the specific version I was trying to revert to.

That same MSDN article has a comment on it pointing to the same fact, and there seems to be a setting for that, which can be changed in two places:

- In the TFS project settings (rightclick the project in Team Explorer -> Team Project Settings -> Source Control):

[image: Team Foundation Server Team Project Source Control Settings]

- A Visual Studio Setting (Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Visual Studio Team Foundation Server):

[image: Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Source Control Settings]

As you can see, both of them are disabled, but I'm still getting the latest version whenever I do a check out, making it impossible to do a rollback.

Is there any other setting I'm missing? Or this isn't the correct way of doing a rollback?

**NOTE:** Using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you 're on VStudio2010 - you can probably forget about that MSDN article.
 Instead, download & install latest [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f), they do come with a nice graphical "Rollback":
[image]
You can also [check](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380776.aspx) `tf rollback`.

Comment: Did it with tf rollback. It's just a bit deceiving that all the UI elements are in place, but then it doesn't work.
Thanks for the tip on TFS Power Tools, will try and use it next time.